# How do I make a loop to look through the elements of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Am fairly new to python and coding in general. So I have a defined list and I'm trying to make a loop that looks through the elements in a list until it matches what I'm looking for and records the position it is in the list.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x = 3
for x in list:
if x == list
print(x, list.index(x))
```

This is my attempt but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work at all mean. What is happening in your code that you think should happen that isn't happening.

Comment: @idjaw I'm trying to use a loop to basically look for the number 3 in that list and the loop stops when it hits number 3, then it prints out the position of the 3 in the list which should be "2".

Comment: Someone just posted an answer that addresses everything. That should answer your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't loop `for x in list`. That will make your `x` value [1,2,3,4] not 3 anymore and beware with the indentation in python. Python is sensitive with **Indentation**. Maybe this is the code you're looking for:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x = 3
for i in list:
    if (i == x):
        print(i, list.index(i))
```

> I forgot that `list` is a built-in syntax. We shouldn't use `list` as variable. Just change it with 'list1' or anything except the built-in syntax name. Here some list of built-in syntax in python https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: You don't need parentheses around your `(i == x)`. It should just be `i == x`. Also using `list` as a name for your *list* will shadow the built-in list, so that name should be changed as well.

Comment: @idjaw - That's true, parentheses not needed in this condition. Save up 2 bytes and I did forget that `list` is a built-in. Yeah it should be another name.

Answer (score 2):

Your search variable is called `x`, and then you call the loop iterator `x` as well, overwriting the search query. Call it something else. Also call `list` something else to avoid masking the built-in. You can also use `enumerate` to properly handle cases where the query appears multiple times. Also, don't forget the colon at the end of the `if` statement.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x = 3
for idx,item in enumerate(l):
    if item == x:
        print(x, idx)
```

Comment: They were also missing a `colon` at the end of their condition. Since they said "it doesn't work at all". I would include that in there to be complete.

Comment: @idjaw - Added an "also."

Answer (score 1):

The problem, aside from the indentation, is that you use same variable `x` for lookup and for the iteration.

Also, it's recommended that you do not use `list` as the variable name, since it is used as a built-in function

Consider the following:

```
_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lookup = 3
for element in _list:
    if lookup == element:
        print(element, _list.index(lookup))
```

Also, if you are certain to use loop to find index, it's better that you use `enumerate` function:

```
_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lookup = 3
for index, element in enumerate(_list):
    if lookup == element:
        print(element, index)
```

If you are just looking to find the index of the element inside the list, you can just use `index` function by itself.

```
_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
lookup = 3
print(lookup, _list.index(lookup))
```

Note that if the lookup is not in the list, `ValueError` would be raised.

Comment: Missing colon in your conditions.

Comment: Thanks, missed that while copypasting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
if x in list:
    print(list.index(x))
```

As idjaw mentioned, though the above piece of code works for your solution, do not use the python keywords such as `list` for other purposes as it overshadows the functionality in the keyword in the local scope. You could always alter the spelling or use a synonym instead. But if it is absolutely necessary to use the same name as of the keyword, the Pythonic way is to use one trailing underscore when renaming your variable. That gives you `list_` which is perfectly alright.

Comment: It would be helpful to also mention to not use `list` as a name for the *list*. Because it shadows the built-in *list*.

Comment: Yes, definitely. I'd add that to my answer.

Comment: This works as well but I'm trying to use a loop to find an element in the list.

Comment: @Langfao, I did not realize that you needed to have the loop in your solution. In that case, others have already addressed that. I'll just keep this up for anyone else who stumbles upon your question and would like a solution that doesn't iterate the entire list.